# ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0 ,keep getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

i am using tensorflow to tarin a model on the images dataset , i rechecked the paths everything is fine this error keep appearing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj28c.png)

this is the code i am using , need help please

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image
```

## Define the paths for the train and val data folders

```
train_folder = 'C:/Users/UnitechSolutions/Desktop/python projects/1st assignment/tensorflow/dataset/train'
val_folder = 'C:/Users/UnitechSolutions/Desktop/python projects/1st assignment/tensorflow/dataset/val'
```

## Define the batch size and number of epochs for training

## Set the variables

```
saved_model_path = 'saved_model.h5'
image_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32
epochs = 20
num_classes = 21
```

## Define the classes

```
classes = ['7up 1.5 liters', '7up 250ml', '7up 500ml', '7up Diet 500ml', '7up Diet TIncan_250ml', '7up Tincan 250ml', 'Dew 1.5Liters', 'Dew 250ml', 'Dew 500ml', 'Dew Tincan 250ml', 'Empty', 'Mirinda 1.5 liters', 'Mirinda 250ml', 'Mirinda 500ml', 'Mirinda Tincan_250ml', 'Pepsi 1.5 Liters', 'Pepsi 250ml', 'Pepsi 500ml', 'Pepsi Tincan 250ml', 'Sting Red 250ml', 'Sting Red 500ml']
```

## Define the number of classes

```
num_classes = len(classes)
```

## Define the path for the pretrained weights

```
pretrained_weights_path = 'C:/Users/UnitechSolutions/Desktop/python projects/1st assignment/tensorflow/'
```

## Define the path for the saved model

```
saved_model_path = 'C:/Users/UnitechSolutions/Desktop/python projects/1st assignment/tensorflow/'
```

## Define a function to parse the XML annotations

```
def parse_annotation(annotation_path):
    tree = ET.parse(annotation_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
```

```
# Get the size of the image
```

```
 size = root.find('size')
    width = int(size.find('width').text)
    height = int(size.find('height').text)

    # Get the bounding boxes for each object in the image
    boxes = []
    labels = []
    for obj in root.findall('object'):
        label = obj.find('name').text
        if label not in classes:
            continue
        label_index = classes.index(label)

        bbox = obj.find('bndbox')
        xmin = int(bbox.find('xmin').text)
        ymin = int(bbox.find('ymin').text)
        xmax = int(bbox.find('xmax').text)
        ymax = int(bbox.find('ymax').text)

        boxes.append([xmin / width, ymin / height, xmax / width, ymax / height])
        labels.append(label_index)

    return boxes, labels
len(train_folder)
len(val_folder)
# Define a function to preprocess the images
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize(image_size)
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    image = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image)
    return image

# Define a function to load the data
def load_data(data_folder):
    images = []
    boxes_list = []
    labels_list = []

    for filename in os.listdir(data_folder):
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            image_path = os.path.join(data_folder, filename)
            annotation_path = os.path.join(data_folder, filename[:-4] + '.xml')
            boxes, labels = parse_annotation(annotation_path)
            images.append(preprocess_image(image_path))
            boxes_list.append(boxes)
            labels_list.append(labels)

    return images, boxes_list, labels_list

# Load the train and val data
train_images, train_boxes_list, train_labels_list = load_data(train_folder)
val_images, val_boxes_list, val_labels_list = load_data(val_folder)




# Define the model
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=image_size + (3,)
)
x = base_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Define the callbacks
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=saved_model_path, save_best_only=True)
early_stopping_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5)

# Define the generators
train_data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    zoom_range=0.1
)
val_data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Define the flow from directory
train_flow_from_directory = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_folder,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    classes=None,
    class_mode='sparse',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
val_flow_from_directory = val_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    val_folder,
    target_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    classes=None,
    class_mode='sparse',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(
    train_flow_from_directory,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_flow_from_directory,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, early_stopping_callback]
)
```

Comment: Hi Mehar, welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to attach the full traceback of your code so the community can help you out more easily.

Comment: Hi, Mehar. Looking at the attached traceback image the issue is with Tensorflow not being able to get the dataset images, please refer to the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images